# How to create two columns for sums from the same column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Type | Date | Amount
```

I used the SUM function to add values in the "Amount" column (as SUM1) when Type has value like 'E'.
Here is my query:

```
select 
  to_char("Date", 'Mon') as mon,
  extract(year from "Date") as yyyy,
  sum("Amount") as SUM1 
from "Transactions"
where "Type" LIKE 'E%' and "Date" between '01/01/2015' and '08/31/2015'
group by 1,2
order by yyyy, mon;
```

This results in rows like:

```
mon | yyyy | SUM1
```

What I would like to do, however, is to also show another sum column (SUM2), to show the sum of adding values from "Amount" where "Type" is like "P", and so show rows like:

```
mon | yyyy | SUM1 | SUM2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your PostgreSQL version. With older ones you can do a conditional sum with `CASE`:

```
select to_char("Date", 'Mon') as mon,
extract(year from "Date") as yyyy,
sum(CASE WHEN "Type" LIKE 'E%' then "Amount" ELSE 0 END) as SUM1,
sum(CASE WHEN "Type" LIKE 'P%' then "Amount" ELSE 0 END) as SUM2
from "Transactions"
where "Date" between '01/01/2015' and '08/31/2015'
group by 1,2
order by yyyy, mon;
```

Or if you're using PostgreSQL 9.4 or newer you can use the nicer `FILTER` syntax:

```
select to_char("Date", 'Mon') as mon,
extract(year from "Date") as yyyy,
sum("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'E%') as SUM1,
sum("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "Type" LIKE 'P%') as SUM2
from "Transactions"
where "Date" between '01/01/2015' and '08/31/2015'
group by 1,2
order by yyyy, mon;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case expression as argument to the sum function to choose what gets summed up like this:

```
select 
    to_char("Date", 'Mon') as mon,
    extract(year from "Date") as yyyy,
    sum(case when "Type" LIKE 'E%' then "Amount" else 0 end) as SUM1,
    sum(case when "Type" LIKE 'P%' then "Amount" else 0 end) as SUM2
from "Transactions"
where "Date" between '01/01/2015' and '08/31/2015'
  and "Type" like 'E%' or "Type" like 'P%'
group by 1,2
order by yyyy, mon;
```